# Gmail API error 429 "User-rate limit exceeded"

Tags: gmail-api

Using Gmail API, I keep getting hundreds of error 429 "User-rate limit exceeded".

My script sends 100 emails at a time, every 10 minutes.

Shouldn't this be within the API limits?

The error pops up after only 5 or 6 successful sends.

Thanks

Comment: If you check google developer console under quota for the gmail api you will see what the user rate limit is for your application.   You should slow down google will block accounts that exceed rate limit on gmail quite quickly its hard to get access back of a google account which has been blocked.  Gmail api really shouldn't be used as an auto mailer.

Comment: I check console, and I'm nowhere near my quota.

Comment: Google doesn't make it up if they say you are exceeding it you are exceeding it. Slow down stop sending so much.   Please edit your question and include your code, maybe there is an error and you are sending more requests then you think.

Answer (score 0):

### Have a look at the [Gmail Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota):

[image]
[image]

[image]

So, if you send 100 emails during a very short time, this corresponds to 10 000 units - thats is 40 times more than the allowed quota per second.

So while short bursts are allowed, if you exceed the quota significantly this might be beyond the scope of the allowed burst.

In this case you should implement [exponential backoff](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/exponential-backoff) as recommended by Google.